# Append last letter in a string to another string

Tags: python

I am constructing a chatbot that rhymes in Python. Is it possible to identify the last vowel (and all the letters after that vowel) in a random word and then append those letters to another string without having to go through all the possible letters one by one (like in the following example)

```
lastLetters = ''    # String we want to append the letters to

if user_answer.endswith("a")
    lastLetters.append("a")

else if user_answer.endswith("b")
    lastLetters.append("b")
```

Like if the word was right we’d want to get ”ight”

Comment: So, like… `lastLetters += user_answer[-1]`…?

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  will "lastLetters += user_answer[-1]" append the last letter in user_answer to lastLetters and then remove it from user_answer? I am new to programming in general, so I have a hard time understanding everything.

Comment: No, it won't remove it from `user_answer`.

Comment: So if I want to do the same thing to the second to last letter, would I write [-2] or [0] then?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/476.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the last index of a vowel, for that you could do something like this (a bit *fancy*):

```
s = input("Enter the word: ") # You can do this to get user input
last_index = len(s) - next((i for i, e in enumerate(reversed(s), 1) if e in "aeiou"), -1)
result = s[last_index:]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
ight
```

An alternative using regex:

```
import re

s = "right"
last_index = -1
match = re.search("[aeiou][^aeiou]*$", s)
if match:
    last_index = match.start()

result = s[last_index:]
print(result)
```

The pattern `[aeiou][^aeiou]*$` means match a vowel followed by possibly several characters that are not a vowel (`[^aeiou]` means not a vowel, the sign ^ inside brackets means negation in regex) until the end of the string. So basically match the last vowel. Notice this assumes a string compose only of consonants and vowels.

Comment: A regex is probably a more straight forward approach…

Comment: The vowels are: **a, e, i, o, u, y**... So, add `y`to your code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is "s" just a random variable name?

Comment: Okay I will add y

Comment: Yes "s" is just a random variable name

Comment: How would I do it if I didn't know that the word would be "right"/ it could be any word?

Comment: just change `s` to `user_answer`

Comment: Okay thank you, and one last question. What does the ^ sign stand for?

Comment: @FelixIversen Added explanation of the regex pattern.